# How do I initialize an array in a struct

Tags: arrays, struct, ethereum, solidity

I have a struct Purchase in which I'm putting an array of payments. However, when I try to add the new payments array in my `makePayment` method I get an error back from the solidity compiler: "Internal compiler error: Copying of type struct Payment memory[] memory to storage not yet supported."  When I change the mayment array to be `storage` or `memory`, I get the same error.  I've added the relevant code below.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do in solidity?  I don't see anything explicitly saying it's not possible in the documentation but I also don't see any examples doing what I'm trying to do.  :|

```
  struct Payment {
    address maker;
    uint amount;
  }

  struct Purchase {
    uint product_id;
    bool complete;
    Payment[] payments;
  }
  Purchase[] purchases;

  function makePayment(uint product_id, uint amt, uint purchase_id) returns (bool) {

      Payment[] payments;
      payments[0] = Payment(address, amt);
      purchases[purchase_id] = Purchase(product_id, false, payments);
  }
```

Comment: It's possible that this was happening because I wasn't using enough gas for the transaction.

Comment: Did you see there is an [Ethereum SE beta](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to manually change the length of the payments array when setting it.

Either use:

```
  Payment[] payments;
  payments[payments.length++] = Payment(address, amt);
```

Or:

```
Payment[] payments;
payments.push(Payment(address, amt));
```

For setting the payments array in Purchase, instead of creating an array and trying to set it to the Purchase.payments you can do the following:

```
uint purchase_id = purchases.length++;
purchases[purchase_id].product_id = product_id;
purchases[purchase_id].complete   = false;
purchases[purchase_id].payments.push(Payment(msg.sender, amt));
```

Extending the purchases length will automatically create the new attributes. Then you can set them manually.

Comment: Does `payments` need the `memory` keyword in this case?

Comment: In solidity 8 this solution won't work as length is read-only, but you can simply do `Purchase p = purchases.push()` instead, and instead of having index, you can do `p.product_id = product_id` and so on

Answer (score 0):

I found this as best solution.

```
  event OnCreateRoom(address indexed _from, uint256 _value);

   struct Room {
      address[] players;       
      uint256 whosTurnId;
      uint256 roomState;
   }  

   Room[] rooms;

   function createRoom() public{
       address[] adr;
       adr.push(msg.sender);
       Room memory room = Room(adr, 0, 0);   
       rooms.push(room);
       OnCreateRoom(msg.sender, 0);
   }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).